# Spring Data JPQL query: lower case for List param

Tags: spring-data, jpql

I use Spring Data REST in my project and I have a @Query tag, as such:

```
@Query("from Customer c where lower(c.customerId) = lower(:customerId) and lower(c.department.businessUnit.name) = lower(:businessUnit)") 
List<Customer> findByCustomerIdAndBusinessUnit(@Param('customerId') String customerId, @Param('businessUnit') String businessUnit)
```

This works perfectly fine. But, I am not sure how to convert to lowercase when a List is passed in, such as:

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE LOWER(c.customerId) IN LOWER(:customerIds)")
Page<Customer> findByCustomerIdIn(@Param("customerIds") List<String> customerIds, Pageable pageable)
```

That gives me the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 94 [SELECT c FROM com.myapp.Customer c WHERE LOWER(c.customerId) IN LOWER(:customerIds)]
```

I understand this happening because Spring Data REST cannot cast a whole list of Strings to lower case (that is not possible in straight up TSQL / PLSQL either!). So, are my options limited to implementing my own repository and build a controller on top of it...? Any better ideas? :)

Comment: Why the need of lower() in the first place? The `customerId` should be a purely technical identifier, and if the ID is aBcD, then the client should pass aBcD, not ABCD or AbCd. Using lower will decrease the performance, and there's no reason to use it in this case, IMHO.

Comment: JB, that is a really good point, but the problem I face is: the code snippet that I quoted above was obfuscated. The "customerId" here is not a unique value issued by the system where it is stored--instead, it is a unique case-insensitive value given to us by our partners to identify locations within the partner's system. Since result of "findByCustomerIdIn" is returned via web service, we have no control over what consumers pass in, so we thought it would best to make it case-insensitive.

Comment: Then you'll have to write some code to transform the list into a list of lowercase strings

Comment: JB, right, I completely agree. The question is though, what is the best way of doing that? Do I need to revert to writing my own REST Controller, or is there some clever way of doing that with Spring Data REST without a custom controller?

Comment: I've never used Spring-Data-Rest. Never understood how it could implement real use-cases without me writing the code. This post just reinforces my feeling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, you have to transform the list.

Even if you plan to use Spring JPA findByQuery like

```
List<User> findByCustomerIdInIgnoreCase(List<String> customerIds);
```

You have to write some code to transform the list into a list of lowercase strings.

If you are looking for converting the list in place, it might not be possible as Strings in Java are immutable

However, if the intention is to do in a single line, with as much less code as possible.

You can do it in Java 8 as below.

```
List<String> customerIdsLC = customerIds.stream().map(String::toLowerCase).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In case, you have a different transformation to do - just provide the right info to map() in the form, Class::method

For e.g.

map(String::toUpperCase) - to convert to Uppercase

map(Long::valueOf) - to convert to Long.

Comment: If you're list has nulls, you'll want to use something like StringUtils::lowerCase instead of String::toLowerCase.